# Connecting ElasticSearch to Superset

Tags: python, elasticsearch, apache-superset

I need to connect ElasticSearch to Superset for visualization. When I checked in Superset in Sources> Databases, it mentioned to use SQLAlchemy URI and Database for testing the connection.

In our case, ElasticSearch is connected with Python library and not using SQLAlchemy.

Is there any way to connect Elastic Search with Superset using Python library and if so could you please help by mentioning the way to connect?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am new to Superset and I need to connect Superset to Elasticsearch and hence when I searched found that using SQLAlchemy to connect to Elasticsearch. Developers are connecting Elasticsearch using Python Library. Now I need to find whether way is there to connect Superset to Elasticsearch using Python Library, so that no need to use of SQLAlchemy. I am not sure how to start with this. Could you please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

you can connect by the way mentioned in the docs.You need to add the dbapi python package mentioned in superset installer document and that will in turn help you connect to the elk using the url elasticsearch+http://{user}:{password}@{host}:9200/

pip install elasticsearch-dbapi

Comment: Hi Parakh, Thanks for your response. I executed pip install elasticsearch-dbapi and then when connecting to Elasticsearch getting the error message as ERROR: {"error": "Connection failed!\n\nThe error message returned was:\nCan't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:elasticsearch.http", "stacktrace": null}.